# How do i get the value of my DropDownListFor assigned to a form view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, http-post, form-submit

I have a ViewModel like which i use on my page, and this has been implemented in a way to contain other ViewModel's as properties, because I have form which needs a separate view model from what the page uses.

**ProductPageViewModel**

```
public class ProductPageViewModel
{
    public ProductViewModel Product { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductBrandViewModel> ProductBrands { get; set; }
}
```

**ProductBrandViewModel**

```
public class ProductBrandViewModel
{
  public Guid ID {get;set;}
  public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

On my View, I have a form which has drop down list which displays the product brand

**Form**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modAddProduct" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "frmAddProduct", @class = "frmAddProduct"}))
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "There seems to be some missing information", new {@class = "alert alert-danger"})
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtProductName" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Description, null, new {id = "txtProductName", @class="form-control", placeholder="Product Name"})
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtProductBrand" class="control-label">Brand:</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductBrands, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductBrands, "ID", "Description"), "Select Product Category", new { id = "ddProductCategory", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can I am using a DropDownListFor helper, which i then use a SelectList with ID and Description as Value and Text, this renders properly in the HTML when i load the page and check the source.

However problem is, when i click the submit button, I do not have my ID passed into the controller action's parameter.

**Controller Action**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel product)
    {
        try
        {
            var productContract = Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, ProductContract>(product);
            _productService.CreateProduct(productContract);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects. You need a `Guid` property to bind the selected `ProductBrandViewModel` to. Change the model to

```
public class ProductPageViewModel
{
   public ProductViewModel Product { get; set; }
   public Guid SelectedBrand { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<ProductBrandViewModel> ProductBrands { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedBrand , new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductBrands, "ID", "Description"), "Select Product Category", new { id = "ddProductCategory", @class = "form-control" })
```

However since you model has a property for the collection, then you can populate that property with all `ProductBrands` items, rather than using `ViewBag` to pass the collection, although the better option would be to make the property

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductBrands { get; set; }
```

and in the controller use

```
model.ProductBrands = new SelectList(db.ProductBrands, "ID", "Description");
```

so that view becomes

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedBrand , Model.ProductBrands, "Select Product Category", new { @class = "form-control" }) // not clear why you want to change the `id` attribute
```

This of course assumes that `ProductViewModel` does not already contain a `Guid` property for the selected Brand (in which case you could just bind to that)

Side note: Generate you labels correctly using `@Html.LabelFor()` (and using the `[Display]` attribute if applicable. Currently your creating `<label>` elements which are not acting as labels (clicking on them will not set focus to the associated control)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your elaborate response, but i still dont get the id when i hit the submit button in the post method in the controller.

Comment: I have updated my code according what you asked me to change now. please see, maybe I am still doing something wrong

Comment: You cannot just completely change your question and invalid my answer (I have rolled back your changes). What problems are your still having?